# Find which column ranges overlap after grouping in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, intervals, genomicranges

I have a huge data frame that looks like this.

I want to `group_by(chr)`, and then for each `chr` to find

- Is any range1 (start1, end1), within the chr group, overlapping with any range2 (start2,end2)?

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <- tibble(chr=c(1,1,2,2),
               start1=c(100,200,100,200),
               end1=c(150,400,150,400),
       species=c("Penguin"), 
       start2=c(200,200,500,1000), 
       end2=c(250,240,1000,2000)
       )

df1
#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#>     chr start1  end1 species start2  end2
#>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1    100   150 Penguin    200   250
#> 2     1    200   400 Penguin    200   240
#> 3     2    100   150 Penguin    500  1000
#> 4     2    200   400 Penguin   1000  2000
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I want my data to look like this.
Essentially I want to check if the range2 overlaps with any range1.
The new data does not change the question, but proof checks the code

```r
# A tibble: 4 × 6
        chr start1  end1 species start2  end2 OVERLAP
         1    100   150 Penguin    200   250    TRUE
         1    200   400 Penguin    200   240    TRUE
         2    100   150 Penguin    500  1000    FALSE
         2    200   400 Penguin   1000  2000    FALSE
```

I have fought a lot with the `ivs` package and `iv_overlaps` with no success in getting what I want.

**Major EDIT:**

---

When I apply any of the codes in real data, I am not getting the results I want, and I am so confused. Why?
The new data dataset does not change the question, but proofs check the code

```
data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~chr, ~start1, ~end1, ~strand, ~gene, ~start2, ~end2,
  "Chr2",   2739,   2840, "+", "A",    740,   1739,
  "Chr2",  12577,  12678, "+", "B",  10578,  11577,
  "Chr2",  22431,  22532, "+", "C",  20432,  21431,
  "Chr2",  32202,  32303, "+", "D",  30203,  31202,
  "Chr2",  42024,  42125, "+", "E",  40025,  41024,
  "Chr2",  51830,  51931, "+", "F",  49831,  50830,
  "Chr2",  82061,  84742, "+", "G",  80062,  81061,
  "Chr2",  84811,  86692, "+", "H",  82812,  83811,
  "Chr2",  86782,  88106, "-", "I",  88107,  89106,
  "Chr2", 139454, 139555, "+", "J", 137455, 138454,
  )

data %>% 
  group_by(chr) %>% 
  mutate(overlap = any(iv_overlaps(iv(start1, end1), iv(start2, end2))))
```

then It gives as an output

```
 chr   start1   end1 strand gene  start2   end2 overlap
   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl>  
 1 Chr2    2739   2840 +      A        740   1739 TRUE   
 2 Chr2   12577  12678 +      B      10578  11577 TRUE   
 3 Chr2   22431  22532 +      C      20432  21431 TRUE   
 4 Chr2   32202  32303 +      D      30203  31202 TRUE   
 5 Chr2   42024  42125 +      E      40025  41024 TRUE   
 6 Chr2   51830  51931 +      F      49831  50830 TRUE   
 7 Chr2   82061  84742 +      G      80062  81061 TRUE   
 8 Chr2   84811  86692 +      H      82812  83811 TRUE   
 9 Chr2   86782  88106 -      I      88107  89106 TRUE   
10 Chr2  139454 139555 +      J     137455 138454 TRUE
```

Which is wrong. They might be indirect matches, but there there is not a direct overlap.

Comment: I think it depends on what you mean by overlap. Check the type argument of iv_overlaps. Can you clarify what you mean by overlap? For instance in your new data, Row 7 overlaps with row 8, at least partially, which is why iv_overlaps return true. Will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Indeed only one-row overlaps. But the rest do not. That's a great catch Maël. So ideally, I should have 9 rows with FALSE and one with TRUE

Comment: Right. Try my code without any then.

Comment: @LDT if you remove the outer `any()` of @Maël's or my answers, you can get 9 rows with FALSE and one with TRUE with the new data, is that what you want? But with that rule your first dataset will get (F, T, F, F). Obviously the two rules in the old and new datasets are not consistent.

Comment: You are right, Darren, but there should be consistent. Theoretically, its something so easy. I want to check if any range2 overlaps with any range1. With `any` I get overlaps that do not exist. It might give a direct outcome to the small dataset, but that does not mean that it is correct. The rule is the same in both datasets. The new dataset does not introduce a new question. It only checks the code

Comment: The main issue was that different interpretations of your question could lead to the same results, which is why when you tried on a different scenario it did not work any more. But now I think we've understood

Comment: You wanted to know if any range2 overlapped with any range1 by the `chr` column, so shouldn't your second example just be `Chr2` -> `TRUE`?

Comment: in the second example, there should be all FALSE except of one that is TRUE. good point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several interpretations to your questions, so here are three possible cases:

1. Within a group, detect for *each* `[start1, end1]` if they overlap with any of `[start2, end2]`.
2. Within a group, detect if *any* of `[start1, end1]` overlap with any of `[start2, end2]`.
3. Within a group, detect if each of `[start1, end1]` overlap with their corresponding `[start2, end2]` (the one on the same row).

In the three cases, you can use `ivs::iv_overlaps`.

---

**Case 1**

`iv_overlaps` will detect, within each group, if the intervals defined in `[start1, end1]` overlap in any way with any of the intervals `[start2, end2]`. It'll return a logical vector of the length of `[start1, end1]`.

```r
library(ivs)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(chr) %>% 
  mutate(overlap = iv_overlaps(iv(start1, end1), iv(start2, end2)))

# A tibble: 4 × 7
# Groups:   chr [2]
    chr start1  end1 species start2  end2 overlap
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>  
1     1    100   150 Penguin    200   250 FALSE  
2     1    200   400 Penguin    160   170 TRUE   
3     2    100   150 Penguin    500  1000 FALSE  
4     2    200   400 Penguin   1000  2000 FALSE
```

---

**Case 2**

If you want to know if *any* (not each) of the intervals 1 overlaps with any of the intervals 2 (so one unique value per group), you should add `any`:

```r
df1 %>% 
  group_by(chr) %>% 
  mutate(overlap = any(iv_overlaps(iv(start1, end1), iv(start2, end2))))

# A tibble: 4 × 7
# Groups:   chr [2]
    chr start1  end1 species start2  end2 overlap
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>  
1     1    100   150 Penguin    200   250 TRUE   
2     1    200   400 Penguin    160   170 TRUE   
3     2    100   150 Penguin    500  1000 FALSE  
4     2    200   400 Penguin   1000  2000 FALSE
```

---

**Case 3**

If you want rowwise overlap detection, then you should use `map2` with `iv_overlaps`:

```r
df1 %>% 
  group_by(chr) %>% 
  mutate(overlap = map2_lgl(iv(start1, end1), iv(start2, end2), iv_overlaps))

# A tibble: 4 × 7
# Groups:   chr [2]
    chr start1  end1 species start2  end2 overlap
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>  
1     1    100   150 Penguin    200   250 FALSE  
2     1    200   400 Penguin    160   170 FALSE  
3     2    100   150 Penguin    500  1000 FALSE  
4     2    200   400 Penguin   1000  2000 FALSE
```

---

**Order of the comparison**

Indeed, if one wants to compare the second intervals with the first, one should use `iv_overlaps(interval2, interval1)`:

```r
# A tibble: 4 × 7
# Groups:   chr [2]
    chr start1  end1 species start2  end2 overlap
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>  
1     1    100   150 Penguin    200   250 TRUE   
2     1    200   400 Penguin    160   170 FALSE  
3     2    100   150 Penguin    500  1000 FALSE  
4     2    200   400 Penguin   1000  2000 FALSE
```

---

Data

```r
df1 <- tibble(chr=c(1,1,2,2),               start1=c(100,200,100,200),               end1=c(150,400,150,400),               species=c("Penguin"),                start2=c(200,160,500,1000),                end2=c(250,170,1000,2000) )
```

Comment: Thank you, Maël. I have put a piece of real data. It seems that in my computer the code does not work for me. I dunno why. Clearly, there are no overlaps and give an overlap. Thank you so so much for taking the time

Comment: Thank you, Maël. I think it still does not work universally with this code. If you have a dataset like this  `df1 <- tibble(chr=c(1,1,2,2),
              start1=c(100,200,100,200),
              end1=c(150,400,150,400),
              species=c("Penguin"), 
              start2=c(200,160,500,1000), 
              end2=c(250,170,1000,2000)
)` 
it gives you an overlap when there is no overlap

Comment: You mean in row 2? there is overlap between row 2 interval 1 and row 1 interval 2.  you don't want to detect overlap  even in that case? so only rowwise? Check my last edit

Comment: I am sorry that I was not clear. It should not be row-wise. We have range2, and then we want to compare each range2 with each range1. If there is overlap, then its TRUE. We want to compare each row of range2, with all rows of range1 and then drive an outcome

Comment: Can you explain to me why you said 'it gives you an overlap when there is no overlap'? what would be the expected outcome here?

Comment: If I understand now, you just need to inverse the intervals in `iv_overlaps`: `df1 %>% 
  group_by(chr) %>% 
  mutate(overlap = iv_overlaps(iv(start2, end2), iv(start1, end1)))`

Comment: you are right. For example in Chr1, you would expect the 200-250 (range 2) interval to have an overlap with the (range1) 200-400. It should TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE

Comment: Great, then inverse the interval is the solution.

Comment: and then at the same time this need to work also for the data. I really admire you Maël for keeping up with this. You are great

Comment: wow thats quite an investigation in here

Answer (score 5):

***Scenario 1:*** Element-wise detection for overlapping

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(chr) %>%
  mutate(OVERLAP = any(start1 <= end2 & end1 >= start2)) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 4 × 7
#     chr start1  end1 species start2  end2 OVERLAP
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>  
# 1     1    100   150 Penguin    200   250 TRUE   
# 2     1    200   400 Penguin    200   240 TRUE   
# 3     2    100   150 Penguin    500  1000 FALSE  
# 4     2    200   400 Penguin   1000  2000 FALSE
```

---

***Scenario 2:*** Element-wise detection for overlapping with sorting

If the intervals are directed, i.e. `end` can be less than `start`, then you need to do sorting before determine overlaps.

```r
df1 %>%
  group_by(chr) %>%
  mutate(OVERLAP = any(pmin(start1, end1) <= pmax(start2, end2) &
                       pmax(start1, end1) >= pmin(start2, end2)))
```

---

***Scenario 3:*** Cross detection for overlapping with sorting

Furthermore, if you want to check if an interval `(start1, end1)` overlaps any of the intervals `(start2, end2)`, as which `ivs::iv_overlaps()` works, then you can implement it with `purrr::map2`.

```r
df1 %>%
  group_by(chr) %>%
  mutate(OVERLAP = any(
    purrr::map2_lgl(start1, end1,
                    ~ any(min(.x, .y) <= pmax(start2, end2) &
                          max(.x, .y) >= pmin(start2, end2)))
  ))
```

Comment: Will this work even if the overlap is on different column?

Comment: I checked and it does not work on the specific case. This depends on what OPs means by `any`

Comment: @Maël Thanks. Yes this depends on OP's request. If he want the effect of `ivs::iv_overlaps()`, I provide an alternative to achieve it.

Comment: Thank you so much Darren for having a look. I tested the code in real data and did not work for me. I posted some real data in the question. Could you also have a look

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check whether the overlap occurs in either direction, you need:

```r
df1 %>%
  group_by(chr) %>%
  mutate(overlap = (max(end1) > min(start2) & min(start2) > min(start1))|
                   (max(end2) > min(start1) & min(start1) > min(start2))) 
#> # A tibble: 4 x 7
#> # Groups:   chr [2]
#>     chr start1  end1 species start2  end2 overlap
#>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>  
#> 1     1    100   150 Penguin    200   250 TRUE   
#> 2     1    200   400 Penguin    200   240 TRUE   
#> 3     2    100   150 Penguin    500  1000 FALSE  
#> 4     2    200   400 Penguin   1000  2000 FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @DarrenTsai yes, you were right - updated now.

Comment: Thank you so so much, Allan. I appreciate you took the time. However, when I check the code in real data I do not take the results I wish, and I am so puzzled. Could you also have a look? A piece of real data is in the question

Answer (score 2):

If your definition of overlap is not overlap as in Darren's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75021631/11732165 but containment `((start1 >= start2 & end1 <= end2) | (start2 >= start1 & end2 <= end1))` then take the answer and use the logic you want.

I use a cross join to make sure you compare all rows under the same `chr`.

Unfortunately there IS undeniably a full containment in your test data -

```
 chr   start1   end1 strand gene  start2   end2 overlap
 7 Chr2   82061  84742 +      G      80062  81061 TRUE   
 8 Chr2   84811  86692 +      H      82812  83811 TRUE
```

[start2, end2] for H is contained in [start1, end1] for G.

Code (note that performance will degrade rapidly if there are a lot of records under a single `chr` - over 200 is likely to be intolerable, and you'll want an implementation that doesn't involve a self-cross.

```
check_overlap = function(df){
  df %>% mutate(temp_id = 1:nrow(df)) %>%
    inner_join(., ., by='chr') %>%
    filter(temp_id.x != temp_id.y) %>%
    mutate(overlaps = start1.x <= end2.y & end1.x >= start2.y) %>%
    group_by(chr) %>%
    summarise(OVERLAP = any(overlaps)) %>%
    inner_join(df, by = 'chr')
}

check_containment = function(df){
  df %>% mutate(temp_id = 1:nrow(df)) %>%
    inner_join(., ., by='chr') %>%
    filter(temp_id.x != temp_id.y) %>%
    mutate(overlaps = (start1.x >= start2.y & end1.x <= end2.y) | (start2.y >= start1.x & end2.y <= end1.x)) %>%
    group_by(chr) %>%
    summarise(OVERLAP = any(overlaps)) %>%
    inner_join(df, by = 'chr')
}
```